# Skip one level of abstraction with Jackson json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have classes like this

```
public class Profile {
  Profile profile
  Interests interests
}


public class Interests {
  HashMap<String,InterestMetric> interests = ...
}
```

if I try serialize it with jackson to json:

```
{
  profile:...
  interests: 
    {
       interests:...
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid creation of 2 interest tags without custom serializer (Annotations) ?

Comment: Why do you have this abstraction on the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
public class Profile {
  Profile profile;
  HashMap<String,InterestMetric> interests = ...
}
```

Why do you need the second class if it only contains the Map?

And on second thought... why does Profile contain a Profile? Shouldn't it only contain the information assembled in a profile?

Edit:
Since you mentioned that the codebase won't change, the [@JsonUnwrapped annotation](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonUnwrapped.html) should be what you are looking for:

```
public class Profile {
  Profile profile
  @JsonUnwrapped
  Interests interests
}


public class Interests {
  HashMap<String,InterestMetric> interests = ...
}
```

I can't test it from where I am, but it should change your output into this:

```
{
  profile:...
  interests:...
}
```

Comment: I need it for operating with interest separately (converting to json and backward). Can I use jackson mapper for converting structure like this (with type annotations) separately. I don't know how to use @JsonDeserialize annotation in this case

Comment: http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonUnwrapped.html <- the @JsonUnwrapped annotation should be what you are looking for then. It allows you to 'inline' property references.

Comment: add this to answer, please

Comment: I edited the answer to give an idea of how it's used. Please try if it is what you are looking for and let us know whether that solves your problem.